# Pandas: merge dataframe with two different timezone column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have df with column `2021-10-01 13:00:00+13:00` and another with `2021-10-01 00:00:00+00:00`, how to merge them properly?

more info, below is how I convert column:

```
df1["tsr"] = pd.to_datetime(df1.tsr, utc=True)
df2["tsr"] = pd.to_datetime(df2.tsr,utc=True).dt.tz_convert("Pacific/Auckland")
```

Below is the table I got with `merge`, and `utc=True`, they are not matched!!

Should I convert them into a string and then merge them???

**minimal reproducible example**

```
df1:
{'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 'tsr': [Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  Timestamp('2021-01-01 01:00:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  Timestamp('2021-01-01 01:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'),
  Timestamp('2021-01-01 02:00:00+0000', tz='UTC')]}
df2:
{'tsr': [Timestamp('2021-10-01 13:00:00+1300', tz='Pacific/Auckland'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 13:30:00+1300', tz='Pacific/Auckland'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 14:00:00+1300', tz='Pacific/Auckland'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 14:30:00+1300', tz='Pacific/Auckland'),
  Timestamp('2021-10-01 15:00:00+1300', tz='Pacific/Auckland')]}
```

The result I want is just matched

```
2021-10-01 00:30:00+00:00   2021-10-01 00:30:00+13:00
2021-10-01 01:00:00+00:00   2021-10-01 01:00:00+13:00
2021-10-01 01:30:00+00:00   2021-10-01 01:30:00+13:00
2021-10-01 02:00:00+00:00   2021-10-01 02:00:00+13:00
```

Comment: They don't merge properly because the time is different,  I would suggest adding a column to each that serves as a key to merge, without the time in it for both,,  df['key']= df['tsr'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')

Comment: @grymlin, Good idea! What is performance compared to converting to epoch time?

Comment: no idea lol, you could add a minimal reproducible example, i think that would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example